# Filas y columnas dinámicas en DataGrid y por cada celda escribir desde un control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

soy nuevo en WPF y estoy intentando crear un DataGrid con 4 columnas definidas "Información de boletos", "Nombre", "Email" y "Código Postal". Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
  System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Información de Boletos");
        table.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        table.Columns.Add("Email");
        table.Columns.Add("ZipCode");
```

Posteriormente pretendo generar filas de manera automática dependiendo de un número dado por el usuario, esta cantidad la guardo en una variable y la utilizo en un ciclo para generar las filas de esta manera:

```
   int cantidad = (int)Application.Current.Resources["NumPeopleQuantity"];
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
        {
            // crear la fila
            System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();

            row["Información de Boletos"] = i + 1;
            row["Nombre"] = "";
            row["Email"] = "";
            row["ZipCode"] = "";

            // insertar la fila en la tabla
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Al final relaciono la tabla al Data grid que he creado de la siguiente manera:

```
Grid1.ItemsSource = ((System.ComponentModel.IListSource)table).GetList();
```

Esto funciona correctamente y se agregan las columnas y filas deseadas al DataGrid. Luce de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo perfecto, puedo escribir un nombre, email y código postal por cada fila desde el teclado de mi computadora, cuando la información se ha llenado correctamente tengo un botón que recupera todo el contenido del dataGrid y lo asigna a un modelo para poder manipularlo en código, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
 System.Data.DataView data = (System.Data.DataView)Grid1.ItemsSource;


        var f = (PaymentViewModel)DataContext;

        string expresion;
        expresion = "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            obj = new DataContactTicket
            {
                CustomerName = data.Table.Rows[i]["Nombre"].ToString(),
                CustomerEmail = data.Table.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString(),
                CustomerZip = data.Table.Rows[i]["ZipCode"].ToString()

            };
            if (obj.CustomerName == "" || obj.CustomerEmail == "" || obj.CustomerZip == "")
            {
                f.Mensaje = "Los campos de información de ticket no pueden estar vacíos";
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                if (Regex.IsMatch(obj.CustomerEmail, expresion))
                {
                    if (Regex.Replace(obj.CustomerEmail, expresion, String.Empty).Length == 0)
                    {
                        nombres.Add(obj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    f.Mensaje = "Favor de validar el formato de correo electrónico";
                    return;
                }
            }
        }



        f.Grid1 = nombres;
```

Hago las validaciones correspondientes y los asigno a una lista en mi ViewModel, todo está correcto, el problema que tengo es que tengo la necesidad de que el usuario escriba esta información desde un onScreenKeyboard y no desde el teclado de una computadora para los textbox es fácil, la referencia queda así:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Height="auto"  Width="500"  FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" TextChanged="TxtMail_TextChanged"
                        Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=onScreenKeyboard}"/>

 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="114,-208,-114,208">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-132,240,0,-240">
                    <TermControls:OnScreenKeyboard x:Name="onScreenKeyboard" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                </StackPanel>
```

La idea es que por cada celda del dataGrid que el usuario seleccione pueda escribir también a través del control en ella, no he encontrado una manera de hacer esto. Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque tu grilla no esta atada al viewmodel, y de esa forma en lugar de definir las columnas por codigo las definis en la vista tambien, y usas ese control que queres?

Comment: Pero cómo haría para referenciar mi control a cada celda del Grid para que pueda escribir sobre ellas?

Comment: No se como funciona ese control como para decirte.. capaz debes replicarlo en cada celda?

Comment: En los TextBox simplemente lo mando a llamar con el ElementName, y cada que oprimo una letra en el control, la dibuja en el textbox, el problema es que no encuentro una propiedad que haga lo mismo para cada celda ya que estas las creo desde el Code Behind y del lado de mi vista sólo está la etiqueta del Grid. No puedo hacer una referencia con ElementName.

Comment: Por eso te sugeri crear las filas en la vista. O si no agregar el control luego programaticamente. No se como funciona ese control, como para decirte que tenes que hacer.

Comment: Alguna idea de agregarlas desde la vista dinámicamente? Ya que la cantidad de filas depende de la cantidad que selecciona el usuario en una vista anterior , por ejemplo si selecciona 2, me crea 2 filas, si selecciona 3, 3 filas y así sucesivamente. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Las filas seleccionadas no deberias ser un problema. Asi como creas las rows aca, si bindeas la grilla a una lista vacia, te ahorras crear las filas a mano, y tambien te ahorras pasar los datos devuelta a tu modelo. la lista, puede ser una List<T> donde T sea un objeto con los datos que vos queres.